# When i tried to configure aws cli it is showing "No module named 'cryptography'" even after installing cryptography

Tags: amazon-ec2, cryptography, aws-cli

When i tried to run aws configure command on ec2 instance it is showing no module name cryptography found .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpEZt.png)

when I tried to install cryptography  It is showing requirement already satisfied [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnaqb.png), I dont know why it is showing no module found if cryptography is already installed

I am having dep ~]$ ^C
[ec2-user@ ~]$ pip show cryptography
WARNING: Package(s) not found: cryptography
[ec2-user@ip- ~]$ pip install cryptography
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting cryptography
Downloading cryptography-41.0.7-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (4.4 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 4.4 MB 4.8 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in /usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages (from cryptography) (1.14.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography) (2.20)
Requirement already satisfied: ply==3.11 in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pycparser->cffi>=1.12->cryptography) (3.11)
Installing collected packages: cryptography
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
awscli 2.9.19 requires cryptography<=38.0.5,>=3.3.2, but you have cryptography 41.0.7 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed cryptography-41.0.7
[ec2-user@ ~]$ pip install --upgrade awscli
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: awscli in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.9.19)
Collecting cryptography<=38.0.5,>=3.3.2
Downloading cryptography-38.0.4-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (4.2 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 4.2 MB 5.7 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<=1.1.0,>=0.7.1 in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from awscli) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: awscrt<=0.17.0,>=0.12.4 in /usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages (from awscli) (0.16.7)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<=3.0.0,>=2.1 in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from awscli) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ruamel.yaml<=0.17.21,>=0.15.0 in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from awscli) (0.16.6)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama<=0.4.7,>=0.2.5 in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from awscli) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit<=3.0.29,>=3.0.24 in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from awscli) (3.0.24)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils<=0.20,>=0.10 in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from awscli) (0.16)
Requirement already satisfied: distro<=1.6.0,>=1.5.0 in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from awscli) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<=1.27,>=1.25.4 in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from awscli) (1.25.10)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in /usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages (from cryptography<=38.0.5,>=3.3.2->awscli) (1.14.5)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit<=3.0.29,>=3.0.24->awscli) (0.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from python-dateutil<=3.0.0,>=2.1->awscli) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography<=38.0.5,>=3.3.2->awscli) (2.20)
Requirement already satisfied: ply==3.11 in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pycparser->cffi>=1.12->cryptography<=38.0.5,>=3.3.2->awscli) (3.11)
Installing collected packages: cryptography
Attempting uninstall: cryptography
Found existing installation: cryptography 41.0.7
Uninstalling cryptography-41.0.7:
Successfully uninstalled cryptography-41.0.7
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
pyopenssl 23.3.0 requires cryptography<42,>=41.0.5, but you have cryptography 38.0.4 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed cryptography-38.0.4
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-11-250 ~]$ pip install --upgrade pyopenssl
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pyopenssl in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (23.3.0)
Collecting cryptography<42,>=41.0.5
Using cached cryptography-41.0.7-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (4.4 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in /usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages (from cryptography<42,>=41.0.5->pyopenssl) (1.14.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography<42,>=41.0.5->pyopenssl) (2.20)
Requirement already satisfied: ply==3.11 in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pycparser->cffi>=1.12->cryptography<42,>=41.0.5->pyopenssl) (3.11)
Installing collected packages: cryptography
Attempting uninstall: cryptography
Found existing installation: cryptography 38.0.4
Uninstalling cryptography-38.0.4:
Successfully uninstalled cryptography-38.0.4
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
awscli 2.9.19 requires cryptography<=38.0.5,>=3.3.2, but you have cryptography 41.0.7 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed cryptography-41.0.7
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-11-250 ~]$ aws configure

No module named 'cryptography'

Comment: What do you see when you run: `pip show cryptography`?

Comment: "[ec2-user@ip-172-31-11-250 ~]$ pip show cryptography
Name: cryptography
Version: 41.0.7
Summary: cryptography is a package which provides cryptographic recipes and primitives to Python developers.
Home-page:
Author:
Author-email: The Python Cryptographic Authority and individual contributors <cryptography-dev@python.org>
License: Apache-2.0 OR BSD-3-Clause
Location: /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: cffi
Required-by: acme, awscli, certbot, josepy, pyOpenSSL"

Comment: I have downgraded that but still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

According to the dependencies that I see for AWS CLI v2, it currently requires cryptography version less than 40.0.2. The version that you show above is 41.0.7. Perhaps you need to downgrade to satisfy the dependency.

```
dependencies = [
    ...
    "cryptography>=3.3.2,<40.0.2",
    ...
]
```

https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/v2/pyproject.toml#L33C35-L33C35